# All of a sudden, getting password undefined on my login - nodejs

Tags: node.js, authentication

I was messing with some other things in the project and when I went back to my login screen that had already been done some time ago and I came across the error:

> if (! results ||! (await bcrypt.compare (password, results [0]
> .password))
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined

I've read my code several times and I can't understand where the problem is, does anyone have any idea what it might be?

console.log (results) brings me a [] as expected since I entered an invalid user to test. The strange thing is that when the typed login is correct, the user is authenticated and when the user does not type an email or password, the expected message appears on the screen informing that information is missing. Only when the user is incorrect that authentication does not work and the message "password undefined" appears.

my login was codded like this:

```
exports.login =  (req, res) => {
try {
    const{email, password} = req.body;

   
  

    if(!email || !password){
        res.clearCookie('myEmail');
        return res.status(400).render('login',{
            message:"A senha ou o e-mail precisa ser preenchido"
            
        })
        
    }
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE email = ?' , [email], async(error,results) =>{
        console.log(results);
        if(!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password,results[0].password))){
            res.clearCookie('myEmail');
            res.status(401).render('login', {
                message:'Email or password is incorrect'
                
                
            })
        }else{
            const id= results[0].id;
            const token = jwt.sign({id: id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET,{
                expiresIn:process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
                
            });
            console.log("the token is"+token)
            const cookieOptions ={
                expires: new Date(
                    Date.now()+process.env.JWT_EXPIRES *24*60*60*1000

                ),
                httpOnly:true
            }
            res.cookie('jwt',token,cookieOptions);
            
            res.status(200).redirect("/userPage")

        }
    })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}





}
```

the redirect

```
router.get('/login',loggedUser,(req,res) =>{

res.render('login')
```

})

loggedUser function used in login router:

```
function loggedUser(req,res,next){
if(req.cookies['myEmail']!=null){
    res.redirect('userPage')
}
        return next()

}
```

Comment: Are you using an JSON middleware? app.use(express.json()) by default express will not parse content

Comment: I did use it in my app.js but the file that was having the issue was not app.js  I discovered the error though. The issue was that for some reason node doesnt see empty array as null and if somebody who is not in mysql try to login may cause errors. I handled that before testing the password and that was it. Thanks for the reply though